# How to move Vue component to a local library?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created some components using template syntax (`*.vue` files), and everything worked fine.

And now I'm trying to move common components to a library.

My component from library (`common/src/component/VButton`):

```
<template>
  <button
  ...
  </button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'VButton',
    ...
  }
</script>
```

Main file from library (`common/src/index.js`):

```
import VButton from './components/button/VButton.vue'
import VButtonLink from './components/button/VButtonLink.vue'
import { ButtonType } from './components/button/ButtonType'

export default {
  VButton, VButtonLink, ButtonType
}
```

Package file from library (`common/package.json`):

```
  "name": "zeus-common",
  ...
  "main": "./src/index.js"
}
```

After that I'm using this library in next way:

`app/package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "file:../common",
    ...
  }
```

`app/src/component/page.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <v-button @click="onClick">Example button</v-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VButton from 'common'

  export default {
    name: 'Page',
    components: { VButton },
    ...
  }
```

As a result I have no errors in console of `npm run serve`, but the component isn't rendered and in the browser console I have this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

Comment: I think it should be `import { VButton } from 'common'`

Comment: No, using with braces `{ VButton }` leads to error "Unknown custom element: <v-button> - did you register the component correctly?"

Answer (score 0):

Have solved problem by removing `default` during export:

```
export {
  VButton, VButtonLink, ButtonType
}
```

And importing as:

```
import { VButton } from 'common'
```